# Answered: The same geom_rect in several graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

To mark several periods in a time series plot I use `geom_rect` like

```
ggplot (peakflow, aes (x = Datum, y = l_min)) +
  geom_rect (xmin = as.Date ("2018-08-03"),
             xmax = as.Date ("2018-09-04"),
             fill = "palegreen",
             ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.01) +
  geom_rect (xmin = as.Date ("2018-09-20"),
             xmax = as.Date ("2018-09-22"),
             fill = "palegreen",
             ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.01) +
  geom_line (colour = "blue")
```

Now I have several dataframes, which shall be marked with the same periods, but I don't want to add the `geom_rect` to every plot (because every now and then a rect is added); this is error prone and not very comfortable.

Is it possible to store the rects and use them later like

```
rects <- geom_rect (...) +
         geom_rect (...)
ggplot (peakflow, aes (x = Datum, y = l_min)) +
  rects + geom_line ()
ggplot (other_df, ...) +
  rects + geom_line ()
```

I know: the above does not work; is there another way?

Comment: I suggest providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - this includes not only the code, but also a sample input, the expected output and its difference from the real output and the full traceback of any error message encountered. Using this question structure makes it easier for SO users to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define multiple geom layers in one object, put them in a list in the form `list(a, b, ...)` rather than `a + b + ...`.

In addition, from your description, it sounds like you'll be better served by `annotate()`, rather than `geom_rect()`, as the latter is meant to work with a data frame, while you are supplying all the dimensions explicitly.

Illustration for list of two geom layers (though in this case, the two rectangles can actually be defined in the same layer...):

```
rects <- list(annotate(geom = "rect", 
                       xmin = as.Date("2018-08-03"),
                       xmax = as.Date("2018-09-04"),
                       ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                       fill = "palegreen", alpha = 0.5),
              annotate(geom = "rect", 
                       xmin = as.Date("2018-09-20"),
                       xmax = as.Date("2018-09-22"),
                       ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                       fill = "palegreen", alpha = 0.5))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  rects +
  geom_point()
```

Sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(as.Date("2018-07-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), 1),
  y = rnorm(184)
)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: While I tried to create an example you solved my problem. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `lapply` as follows.

```
# generate sample data
dat1 <- head(iris, 20)
dat2 <- tail(iris, 20)

plots <- lapply(list(dat1, dat2), function(x) {

  # replace this good with your function
  ggplot(data = x, mapping = aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth()

})
```

Result

```
plots[[1]]
```

[image]

```
plots[[2]]
```

[image]

---

If you want to store your `geom`s you can do

```
my_geoms <- function() {
  list(geom_point(),
       geom_smooth())
}

ggplot(dat1, mapping = aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + 
  my_geoms()
```